# How would you approach the second part of this series question?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove by induction that for all natural numbers $n$, $n>1$
> $$\sum_{r=1}^nr(r+1)(r+5)=\frac{1}{4}n(n+1)(n+2)(n+7)$$
> Hence write down an expression for in $n$ for the sum of the series.
> $$\sum_{r=n+1}^{2n}r(r+1)(r+5)$$
> (Do not attempt to simplify the expression

I've attempted the first part and I seem to have proven that it is true. I'm just lost with how to even approach the second part about writing an expression. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have solved the first part, so you know the sum of the first $n$ terms is $F(n)$, then the answer to the second sum is $F(2n)-F(n)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: Thank you very much